# XML signature, ORACLE PLSQL, SHA1 digest value calculation

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, sha1, signature

I've been strugling with digest value calculation and now i'm out of ideas. Here's xml example and digest value generated by SoapUI:

```
<ds:Reference URI="#TS-5C3C8278F62662ED251468430162870278">
   <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
         <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse soapenv xsi" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      </ds:Transform>
   </ds:Transforms>
   <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
   <ds:DigestValue>FP+KnVZ5S8C/RW6sBvulTUYYKAA=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

And reference:

```
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-5C3C8278F62662ED251468430162870278">
  <wsu:Created>2016-07-13T17:16:02.870Z</wsu:Created>
  <wsu:Expires>2016-07-13T17:21:02.870Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
```

Here's my oracle code:

```
declare
  l_clob clob;
  l_hash raw(20);
begin
  select
  xmlSerialize(
    document extract(
      xmlType('<wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="TS-5C3C8278F62662ED251468429256802268">
        <wsu:Created>2016-07-13T17:00:56.802Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2016-07-13T17:05:56.802Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>'), '/*'))
  into
    l_clob
  from
    dual;

  l_hash := dbms_crypto.Hash(
    l_clob,
    DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH1);

  dbms_output.put_line(
    utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
      utl_encode.base64_encode(
        l_hash)));
end;
/
```

Output: 5SiW/yo1nYIujurXbp5Ob9z6Mbs=

Note that i added WSU namespace to xml, since without it i can't be canonalized.

Without WSU namespace and canonilization:

```
declare
  l_clob clob := '<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-5C3C8278F62662ED251468429256802268"><wsu:Created>2016-07-13T17:00:56.802Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2016-07-13T17:05:56.802Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp>';
  l_hash raw(20);
begin
  l_hash := dbms_crypto.Hash(
    l_clob,
    DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH1);

  dbms_output.put_line(
    utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
      utl_encode.base64_encode(
        l_hash)));
end;
/
```

Output: tV9e2gUBqG9tgUXXwuc2M9/C798=

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that inclusive namespaces must be added to element, in this example "wsse soapenv xsi" and then they must be ordered, i.e. "<... soapenv:... wsse:... wsu:... xsi:... wsu:Id=...>...<.../>", only then one can calculate digest value.